# Sql Group by datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by

I have a `MySql` table :

```
+--------------------+----------------+
| datetime           | energy         |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 2010-06-15 10:00:00|               1|
| 2010-06-15 10:15:00|               3|
| 2010-06-15 10:30:00|               6|
| 2010-06-15 10:45:00|               7|
| 2010-06-15 11:00:00|               9|
| 2010-06-15 11:15:00|              12|
| 2010-06-15 11:30:00|              15|
| 2010-06-15 11:45:00|              28|
| 2010-06-15 12:00:00|              52|
| 2010-06-15 12:15:00|              75|
| 2010-06-15 12:30:00|              88|
| 2010-06-15 12:45:00|             102|
| 2010-06-15 13:00:00|             150|
| 2010-06-15 13:15:00|             189|
| 2010-06-15 13:30:00|             200|
| 2010-06-15 13:45:00|             205|
| 2010-06-15 14:00:00|             209|
| 2010-06-15 14:15:00|             400|
| 2010-06-15 14:30:00|             450|
| 2010-06-15 14:45:00|             480|
| 2010-06-15 15:00:00|             500|
+--------------------+----------------+
```

I would obtain the production of every hour as difference between max and min of every hour:

**example:**

production of hour 10 is given by prod. of hour 11 (value = 9)  less production of hour 10 (value = 1)  -> result = 8

**Expected result**

```
+--------------+----------------+
| datetime     | energy         |
+--------------+----------------+
| 2010-06-15 10|               8|
| 2010-06-15 11|              43|
| 2010-06-15 12|              98|
| 2010-06-15 13|              69|
| 2010-06-15 14|             291|
+--------------+----------------+

select max(energy) - min(energy) 
FROM tableA
group by hour(datetime)
```

this query doesn't work because make the difference between 10:45 and 10:00 ( not 11:00 and 10:00)

Any advice ?

Comment: Do you want the difference between the max and min, or between the start of one hour and the start of the next hour?

Comment: Is energy always increasing, so they're the same thing?

Comment: I want the difference between max and min even if energy is always increasing because sometimes samples can be missing.

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference between each hour, use a self-join that relates times that are an hour apart.

```
SELECT a.datetime, b.energy - a.energy AS energy
FROM tableA AS a
JOIN TableA AS b ON a.datetime = DATE_SUB(b.datetime, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
WHERE MINUTE(a.datetime) = 0
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/SWVHL60942)

Comment: I need the difference between max and min even if energy is always increasing because sometimes samples can be missing

i'm not sure of having every  XX:00 minute

Comment: But if you want the max in hour 10, why would it use the energy from 11:00? That's not in the same hour.

Comment: What if 10:45 is higher than 11:00, should you use that as the max?

Comment: Can you change your example to show all the different cases, and what the expected result should be?

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE WITH MISSING DATA

+--------------------+----------------+
| datetime           | energy         |
+--------------------+----------------+
| 2010-06-15 10:00:00|               1|
| 2010-06-15 10:45:00|               7|
| 2010-06-15 11:00:00|               9|
| 2010-06-15 11:15:00|              12|
| 2010-06-15 11:30:00|              15|
| 2010-06-15 11:45:00|              28|
| 2010-06-15 12:15:00|              75|
| 2010-06-15 12:30:00|              88|
| 2010-06-15 12:45:00|             102|
| 2010-06-15 13:00:00|             150|
| 2010-06-15 13:15:00|             189|
| 2010-06-15 13:30:00|             200|
| 2010-06-15 13:45:00|             205|
| 2010-06-15 14:00:00|             209|
| 2010-06-15 14:15:00|             400|
| 2010-06-15 14:30:00|             450|
| 2010-06-15 14:45:00|             480|
| 2010-06-15 15:00:00|             500|
+--------------------+----------------+

In this example some samples are missing.

Expected result:

+--------------+----------------+
| datetime     | energy         |
+--------------+----------------+
| 2010-06-15 10|               8|  11:00 to 10:00
| 2010-06-15 11|              17|  11:45 to 11:00
| 2010-06-15 12|             150|  13:00 to 12:15
| 2010-06-15 13|              69|  13:00 to 14:00
| 2010-06-15 14|             291|  14:00 to 15:00
+--------------+----------------+

I always want to group by a complete hour:
From 10:00 to 11:00 included
From 11:00 to 12:00 included
From 12:00 to 13:00 included
ecc....
[immagine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZjTB.jpg)